# update last record of matching condition in single query

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to update last record of matching condition.i am getting more than one result in code so i did it different way.

```
$u = user_payments::where('id', $id)->where('staff_id', $staffId)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
$up = user_payments::where('id', $u->id)->update(['transaction_id' => $transaction_id]);
```

here i have to query two times so it call DB two times as i want to optimise the query, I tries as above but i want to it in single query... How can i do this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you need. Ultimately only one single update script runs on the database.

```
$result = user_payments::where('id', $id)
    ->where('staff_id', $staffId)
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->take(1)
    ->update(['transaction_id' => $transaction_id]);
```